# Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

Here is my code and my operation,I want to debug my code one step by step(the follow code just a example)
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern int addd(int ,int);

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    int a = 10,b = 20;

    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

opr.cpp

```
int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I use a template makefile form [makefiletemplate](https://github.com/Cheedoong/MakefileTemplate) just modify something not usual,when I make the g++ command :

```
[root@centos-linux-10 52coder]# make
g++ -std=c++11 -g   -O3 -Wall -Wextra      -c opr.cpp -o opr.o
g++ -std=c++11 -g   -O3 -Wall -Wextra      -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -g   -O3 -Wall -Wextra         ./opr.o ./main.o  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all   -o torun
Type ./torun to execute the program.
```

I use -O3 2 1,all got wrong.
I just want to debug the code from function main step by step,something wrong like this:

```
[root@centos-linux-10 52coder]# gdb torun 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-110.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/52coder/patchtool...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b main
Function "main" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) b /root/52coder.cpp:8
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) show directories
Source directories searched: $cdir:$cwd
```

Can anybody please tell me what should I do for this problem,thanks for advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't call the `add` function. And to debug code, don't use the optimisation options like `-O3`.

Comment: Avoid compiling as *root*

Comment: Avoid doing anything as root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (easily) debug a [*stripped*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) executable. Because the GDB debugger needs the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information in it.

So link your code with just:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -g   -O3 -Wall -Wextra ./opr.o ./main.o  -o torun
```

You may find easier to debug programs with less [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. `-O0` or `-Og` or `-O1` at most, instead of `-O3`).

PS. There is some way to put the debug information in a *different* file, but that is a different question (and Linux specific).

Comment: you saved me from the stuck,I delete the -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all from the makefile,thanks for your answer! [makefiletemplate](https://github.com/Cheedoong/MakefileTemplate/blob/8522819191627da4ae11174ef213a0c38bd7bdcb/Makefile#L55)

Answer (score 2):

Your source file is not called `/root/52coder.cpp`, so it shouldn't be surprising that GDB doesn't recognise it as a source file that it auto-loaded during debugging of your program.

I guess you meant `b /root/52coder/main.cpp:8` or just `b main.cpp:8`.

You will also need to get rid of the symbol stripping as Basile has already described, otherwise the debugger is not going to be able to use your source at all, even with the correct filename.

Comment: that's a spell mistake,I just use the right path and name ,also can't use gdb.The reason is Basile Starynkevitch,I just delete -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all ,everything goes fine.